# generating a alphanumeric code using javascript in code generation, by clicking a button in form

Tags: javascript, html, alphanumeric

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to pass the alphanumeric code (generated by javascript) in to the html textbox by clicking a html button?

So what I mean is, I have a textbox and a button, if I clicked the button it will get the generated code from a java script code and it will be displayed in the textbox...

Here's my code (if you can edit this, please edit the whole code...):

```
<html>
  <head><title> Untitled Document </title></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function randomString(length, chars) {
        var mask = '';
        if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
        var result = '';
        for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
          result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))];
        }
        return result;
      }
      document.write(randomString(16, 'aA#'));
    </script>
    <form>
      <label for="gencode"> Generated Code: </label>

      <!-- here is the problem I don't know what am I -->
      <input type="text" id="gencode" name="gencode">

      <!-- going to put on he onclick and on the value -->
      <input type="button" value="generate now">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write`. Please do not use this anymore. Use DOM methods like `document.getElementById()` and `node.appendChild()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, what you're trying to do with the masking and whatnot, I'm just taking your word for it. That's not my area of specialty. However, I think this works out the problem you were having.

Note, IE8 and 7 support `node.attachEvent` instead of `node.addEventListener`. IE9 *does* support `node.addEventListener`, though. If you need support for those older IE versions, you'll need to do some checking:

```
if (addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', myClickHandler);
} else if (attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent('onclick', myClickHandler);
}
```

Note the `click` and `onclick` differences.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Generate Code</h1>
<form>
    <label for="length">Length: </label>
    <input type="text" id="length" name="length" value="10">
    <label for="characters">Characters: </label>
    <input type="text" id="chars" name="chars" value="akdie">
    <label for="gencode"> Generated Code: </label>
    <input type="text" id="gencode" name="gencode">
    <button type="button" id="generate">Generate Now</button>
</form>​
```

**Javascript**

```
function randomString() {
    var gencode = document.getElementById('gencode'),
        length = document.getElementById('length').value,
        chars = document.getElementById('chars').value,
        mask = '',
        result = '';

    console.log(length, chars);

    if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';

    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
        result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))];
    }

    console.log(result);

    gencode.value = result;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function load(){
    document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', randomString);
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ub26g/